# onTouch Not working properly

Tags: java, android, ontouchlistener

Okay, so I'm making a simple stopwatch thing, and when you press anywhere on the screen, I want it to start the time, but for now, just print something in the output. I've looked at a lot of examples, a I look at a lot of other questions with answers, none of them worked. This is what I have so far (The onTouch is at the bottom of it):

```
package com.timeofcubeeliteDYLANFERRIS.cubetimerelite;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.AlertDialog.Builder;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
final private int RANDOM_DIALOG = 0;
String message;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch(item.getItemId())
    {
    case R.id.settingsMenu: 
        Intent intent = new Intent (MainActivity.this, MainPreferenceActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        break;
    case R.id.cubetypeMenu:
        Intent cubeTypeIntent = new Intent (MainActivity.this, PreferenceCubeType.class);
        startActivity(cubeTypeIntent);


        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        String value = preferences.getString("test", "String not found");
        System.out.println(value);
        Log.d("Cubetimer:", value);
        break;
    default:
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}






public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event){
    int action = event.getAction();
    switch(action){
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: Log.d(message, "down"); break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: Log.d(message, "move"); break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: Log.d(message, "up"); break;

    }
    System.out.println("Oh my oh MY...");
    return true;
}

}
```

So, how would I fix the touch event? (I don't care to preserve the ACTION_UP, DOWN, MOVE. THat's just what I was trying to test with)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you haven't override the right event. That's why your method is not called.

You should use `onTouchEvent` instead, like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    //Do your stuff
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: Okay, I did what you said, added the override, and the new return, but it errors, saying "...Must override or implement a supertype method". No idea what that means

Comment: Have you removed you "onTouch" method. You should just use onTouchEvent

Comment: @DXPower : you will need to implement `OnTouchListener`  Listener in Activity to override onTouch method in Activity

Comment: That fixed it, I didn't see that change there. Thanks, bro. :D